# No Module Named 'Ocr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

Working on an OCR. I can import asprise_ocr_api and I want to work on this:

```
from asprise_ocr_api import *
Ocr.set_up()
ocrEngine = Ocr()
ocrEngine.start_engine("eng")
s = ocrEngine.recognize("1.png", -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
OCR_RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, OCR_OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT)
print("Result: " + s)
ocrEngine.stop_engine()
```

becasuse the code fail:

OUTPUT:

```
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\KOFAI(Knight Online Arfiitical ^ 
 Intelligince\MNIST.py", line 1, in <module>
 from asprise_ocr_api import *
 File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
 packages\asprise_ocr_api\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 from ocr import *
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocr'
```

I keep getting this error. I Need Help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asprise_ocr_api` module doesn't do submodule imports correctly in Python 3.

For example `__init__.py` contains `from ocr import *`. For a sub-module in Python 3 that should be `from .ocr import *`. Idem for `from ocr_app import OcrApp, run_ocr_app`. That should be `from .ocr_app import OcrApp, run_ocr_app`.

After making these changes in all files it imports correctly.

Comment: That's Works Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
easy_install tinyocr
```

Or

```
pip install tinyocr
```

Or, follow the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ocr).

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ocr (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ocr

Comment: Please, if you are not sure if it works, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: i mean tinyocr everyone know it

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install asprise_ocr_sdk_python_api
```

See http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/python-ocr-sdk-asprise_ocr_api-overview.html

Comment: This is the right answer. The other answer points to installing modules which do not exist.

Comment: @COLDSPEED It's *not* the right answer. The OP has already installed the package, which for some reason doesn't handle imports correctly; maybe it was tested with an older version of Python.